# Rendering PDF in Window 8

Tags: pdf, windows-8, windows-runtime, pdfrenderer

I'm looking for a component for WinRT (Windows 8 Metro) to be able to render PDFs. I cannot use the Reader app for security reason and I must add some overlay on the rendered PDF.

Does any one has an idea? Any PDF lib that is working in WINRT? I can also imagine rendering the Pages to images and then show the images

Comment: You could try pdf.js for client-side rendering https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js  I've not tried it, thus comment and not answer. :)

Comment: in my case, a "sever side" solution is not an option. I have to integrate with an existing system.

Comment: For future readers of this post, [Amyuni PDF Creator for WinRT is currently available as pre-release trial](https://www.amyuni.com/en/resources/trialdownloads/). This a commercial library that allows rendering PDF files in WinRT apps. It can be used as a Xaml control in Xaml-based projects or as a PDF-to-HTML5 converter in WinRT-Javascript projects. *Usual disclaimer applies*